# Firebug "break on all errors" feature breaks much too often

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firebug

When switching on Firebug's "Break on all Errors" mode in the console, it breaks on all kinds of errors which would actually not cause a real problem, even "assignment to undefined variable".

This results in lots of breaks inside jQuery and various jQuery UI plugins. It's so bad that I cannot use this feature at all, even though it would make debugging much less bothersome.

Am I the only one having this problem? If not, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are legitimate breaks you're seeing...for instance something like this:

```
undefinedVarName = "something";
```

Is not technically legal, and actually won't work in strict mode...you need to define a variable, even if it's at a higher scope before you use it, this is both good practice and...well...the correct way to do things.

The libraries themselves I've not come across the breaks you describe.  Plugins? sure, if they're not well written they'll throw errors...you can either fix them or deal with it, but it's Firebug's job to complain about badly written JavaScript, and it's doing just that.

Comment: I know that it is an error in strict javascript mode, however most jquery plugins (even jquery.ui) are not 100% strict mode compliant. In a perfect world all third plugins would be nicely coded, but in this reality I am looking for a practical workaround. Fixing dozens or hundred of code lines with non-critical syntax errors just to please Firebug isn't one of them.

Comment: @Adrian - I don't see these errors in jQuery UI, not since 1.8+, which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.8. For instance I see sporadic errors when running some animations. Other irrelevant errors are in jquery.validate and jquery.metadata which are also very popular plugins. IE does not break on such errors, but it always breaks on relevant ones.

Comment: @Adrian - do you have some examples?

Comment: Simply reloading this page in "break on all errors" mode gives me a handful of errors. Clicking on "add comment" to your post gave me another few.

Comment: @Adrian - I'm not seeing any of these errors, my screen is clear with break on all. I'm testing with Firebug 1.5.4, Firefox 3.6.12, are you on the firefox beta? or some plugins/user scripts you're running?

Comment: Same Firebug and Firefox versions. I also just tried it with Firebug on my laptop, and break on all errors did not break at all on this page, instead it showed me a "security code 1000" script error in the console. Which is also weird, but different. I guess that the answer is that that Firebug itself is still very very buggy... :-\

Comment: @Adrian - I imagine it's a extension causing your issues here, can't be sure though...I run only firebug and web dev toolbar in Firefox, try disabling extensions until you find the culprit?

Comment: I just disabled all extensions related to Firebug, but still no dice. I'll try re-installing Firefox on a second account when I have more time. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Adrian - welcome, sorry you're seeing such wacky results, hopefully a clean install will do the trick.